# Given a ciphertext in RSA which is not comprime with our N, can we get the secret key?

Tags: rsa

If we are given a ciphertext which is not coprime with our N (N = p*q), is there any way to get the secret key from this information in RSA?

I first thought you could divide the N by our ciphertext C, giving us a non-trivial factorization of N i.e. C * (N/C). But then we would be stuck trying to find $\phi(C)$ and $\phi(N/C)$, which I suppose is not easier than factoring N in the first place, if they are not primes. Can it be done?

Comment: Ehhm if you have the ciphertext and it's not co-prime with the modulus, what is the GCD of the two numbers?

Comment: I actually don't know. I figured it has something to do with that, but I've been staring myself blind looking at the properties of GCD on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor

Comment: I know it's either p or q, but I don't understand the reasoning behind this. Could you explain? Couldn't gcd(C,N) just return C again, since N is divisible with C?

Comment: If it just returned C again, then you know that C is one of the factors of N and thus either p or q and you _basically found the private key_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $N=p\cdot q\quad,p,q\in\mathbb P$ be a semi-prime (as in RSA). Further let $a$ be *any* number for now. $$\gcd(a,N)$$ can now take exactly 4 values:

1. $\gcd(a,N)=1$
2. $\gcd(a,N)=p$
3. $\gcd(a,N)=q$
4. $\gcd(a,N)=N$

because there are no other factors of $N$ which could be the greatest *common divisor*.
Now let's take $c$ (your cipher text) instead of $a$. We can exclude case 1 because we know $c$ and $N$ are not co-prime (remember how co-prime is defined as $\gcd(a,b)=1$?). We can exclude case 4, because $c$ is an RSA ciphertext and thus was reduced $\bmod N$ before and this automatically ensures that $c<N$. Furthermore $c$ is supposed to be a ciphertext for which the case $m=0$ probably happens with negligible probability and the only encryption that can yield $m=0$ is one of multiple (including 0) of the modulus, i.e. only 0, if we assume $m<N$ as usual (which excludes the case where $m=0$ which would yield $\gcd(c,N)=N$)([thanks poncho](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/41359/given-a-ciphertext-in-rsa-which-is-not-comprime-with-our-n-can-we-get-the-secre/41361?noredirect=1#comment94383_41361) [and fgrieu](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/41359/given-a-ciphertext-in-rsa-which-is-not-comprime-with-our-n-can-we-get-the-secre#comment94394_41361)). Also note that you don't need to bother with the key at all if $c=0$ because you directly *know* that $m=0$.

Now we're left with only two possible options: $p$ and $q$. So the $\gcd$ *has* to be one of that. And if we know one of the factors of $N$, everything else follows trivially.

Also note that "a and b are co-prime" is equivalent to $\gcd(a,b)> 1$ and that this doesn't have to imply $a=k\cdot b$ for some k, because it may also be that $a=pq$ and $b=mp$ which would yield $\gcd(a,b)=p$. For a concrete example consider $a=10$ and $b=15$.

Comment: Here's the thing I don't still don't understand (sorry!). Why can't $\gcd(a, N)$ take on other than those 4 values? I suppose there are many more values than p and q that divide N (e.g. the C I found didn't have to be either of those, otherwise C in my question would trivially have been p or q). These numbers would be divisors of N, which in turn could be a divisor for any number which you want to run gcd on together with N.

Comment: @Amnestic OK, I can't expand my answer now (give me up to a day with that), but there can't be any other divisors of N except the trivial ones (N and 1) and p and q because the prime factorization of a number is unique and every other number would have to divide p or q to divide N but because they're prime, they don't have any such divisors.

Comment: I'm sorry to keep running in circles, but if only 1, p, q and N can divide N, why is it C can divide N without being either p or q (or the trivial divisors).

Comment: @Amnestic C doesn't have to be able to divide N to be "not co-prime". As a simple example imagine C=2*p which clearly doesn't divide N but yet the GCD would be p.

Comment: Actually, there's a third possible option: $a=0$; that doesn't reveal the factorization of $N$ :-)

Comment: @SEJPM: the case of $a=0$ and $N>0$ gives $\gcd(a,N)=N$, not  $\gcd(a,N)=0$ (notice that $N$ divides both $0$ and $N$; also, $0$ is never a valid divisor). So we have 4 cases and can not exclude $\gcd(a,N)=N$, as it can happen when $a=0$.